# why is css not being applied to this jquery anchor button?

Tags: jquery-ui, button

I must be missing something very basic in the CSS. My jQuery anchor button is functional, but it's rendering as a simple underlined label, not asa rounded-corner UI button. I would be grateful if someone could point out the error in this simple example.

Thanks

```
!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML LANG="en-US">
<HEAD>
<TITLE>button test</TITLE>

<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="Sat, 22 May 2010 00:00:11 GMT">
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(

    function() {

        $('a','.test').click(function(){showIntro();return false;});

     });


function showIntro()
{   
   document.location.href="intro.htm";  
}


</script>

<body>

<div class='test'><a href="#">Button</a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually make it a button using [`.button()`](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Button), like this:

```
$(function() {
  $(".test a").button();
});
```

You can see the [jQuery UI demos here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/) and [a demo of your markup working here](http://jsfiddle.net/564Yu/).

Comment: you do not need a button to call click

Comment: @Daveo - I think you misunderstood the question, the question was why didn't it **look** like a button... "it's rendering as a simple underlined label, not as a rounded-corner UI button."  I don't think I implied you needed this to have a `click` handler anywhere...just that you need `.button()` or to manually apply the relevant styles and elements to make it a button.

Comment: @Nick: I was following the example page you cited almost verbatim. IF you check out the View Source link there, you will see that my code and markup are virtually identical to the example. How is that example page getting the anchor button to render with rounded corners?

Comment: @Tim - That example calls `.button()` like my answer, it's missing from your code: `$("button, input:submit, a", ".demo").button();`

Comment: @Nick, the example does not call .button() on the anchor-button, though it does call .button() on the button-button.  But you're right, calling .button() will cause the CSS to be applied.

Comment: @Nick: the example has this: 

$("a", ".demo").click(function() { return false; });

Comment: @Tim - It calls the button on `<button>`, `<input type="submit">`, and `<a>`, look at the selector: `$("button, input:submit, a", ".demo").button();`  It's doing `.button()` on all 3 types of elements, then *also* attaching a click handler to the anchor.

Comment: @Nick, I completely missed the multiple selectors. I didn't even know that was possible! Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the proper class to the link, using jQuery or otherwise.

Try:

```
<a href="#" class="ui-button">Button</a>
```

Comment: There are many more classes and a wrapped element in play here, just adding the `ui-button` class won't do it :) See here for an example of that: http://jsfiddle.net/jG5Ch/

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to make it a button you just need

> ```
>   $(".test a").click(function(){showIntro();return false;});
> ```

What you are trying to do with your selector passing the second paramater is the Scope.
The second paramater is not mean to be a string (selector)  it should be a jQuery Object.

So if you wanted to do it your way your would have to say

> var test = $('.test');
>
> $('a',test).click...

But the 1st method is prefered over doing it this way.

Comment: This wasn't the question...that's why there's CSS in the title of the question, I think you should re-read the question.  The `click` handling already works, even if it has extra code and an extra `document.ready` wrapper...but this answer doesn't answer the question at all.  Also, it's factually incorrect, here's a demo showing a string/selector for the context works: http://jsfiddle.net/s7BAw/

Comment: I was following the example here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/  and it looked to me as though the second parameter was referring to the container DIV:  

      $("a", ".demo").click(function() { return false; });

 Here is the markup: 

    <div class="demo">

 <button>A button element</button>
 
 <input type="submit" value="A submit button">
 
 <a href="#">An anchor</a>

      </div><!-- End demo -->

Sorry if this gets wrapped and unformatted.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to be providing an answer, if not "the" answer, to my own question, but I have discovered a clue as to what's going on, if not the ultimate cause of the behavior.  Below is code cut and pasted from the Button example on the jQuery website; take it to jsFiddle and run it: it works. But if you remove this line relating to the input-button:

```
 $("button, input:submit, a", ".demo").button();
```

then the anchor-button fails to render properly. Why is the anchor-element's rendering dependent on the existence of the input-button?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("button, input:submit, a", ".demo").button();

        $("a", ".demo").click(function() { return false; });
    });
    </script>
    <style>

    </style>



<div class="demo">

    <button>A button element</button>

    <input type="submit" value="A submit button">

    <a href="#">An anchor</a>

</div><!-- End demo -->
```

​